# Flutter can I save the widget keys in a static vars or in provider state?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget, state-management

I want to save the widget key in a static variable to be used later at  any time or save it in a provider state (like Provider managment state) to be used in any inherited widgets .The reason for that I want to access the state of particular widgets in the app in order not to repeat the same logic in each widget.

Comment: You can try creating static variable on widget class, & call like `className.myKey`

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh Thank you for your response but what if the key is recreated during build in this case I set the static var again ?

Comment: you can create static const/final that will be same, you can create const valueKey depend on your scenario.